# Wamp server startup error "-can not startup [Ephase error]"

Tags: php, wamp

After I download the WAMP Server, a windows pop out stating:

> The configuration file contains a syntax error on line
>   1235;[EParseError]parameter "service "specifies an unknown service .

I have no idea what type of this problem. Did anyone facing this type of problem? How can I solve this type of problem?

Comment: Post content of your wampmanager.ini at line 1235.

Comment: I have the same problem. The line contains the following:
Action: service; Service: ; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: waituntilterminated

Comment: @csaron92 In your case seems missed wampapache parameter. This line should look like: Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: waituntilterminated

Answer (score 8):

If you're installing WAMP 2.5 and above, you have to make sure that you uninstall any previous version first. Backup your `www` folder, `php.ini`, `my.ini` and `httpd-vhosts.conf` files.

Then try follow these steps in order to remove the old services:

1. Launch WAMP server, disregard that it doesn't light green.
2. Click on the tray icon, then: Stop All Services.
3. Tray icon -> Apache -> Service -> Remove Service
4. Tray icon -> MySQL -> Service -> Remove Service

Run command prompt (cmd.exe) and execute the following commands:

```
sc delete wampapache

sc delete wampmysqld
```

Then perfom these steps:

1. Tray icon -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
2. Tray icon -> MySQL -> Service -> Install Service

Also make sure you're running WAMP Apache and MySQL server (each setting can be found in corresponding ini file) on other ports if your default port 80 is used for another server and 3306 is used for another database server.

Comment: This solved it for me, thanks. Turned out I had forgotten about an older version of wamp already installed on my system.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to start/stop wamp server with Command Prompt (Admin)

NET START wampapache
NET START wampmysqld

NET STOP wampapache
NET STOP wampmysqld

Comment: Please note that you should use NET START wampmysqld64 if using the 64bit edition.

Comment: I had an error like above (but on line 0) but the mysql version worked (allowing me to make a backup) and the apache didn't

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error when I tried to install the 64bit version of wamp2.5 on Windows 8.1. I tried the 32bit version instead, and it worked (install/run as an Admin).

Comment: This has nothing to do with OS 32-bit or 64-bit architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I  had a similar problem. There are ways to solve the problem like copying over the orgional conf  and ini file: http://colorsinweb.wordpress.com/2014/04/06/the-configuration-file-contains-a-syntax-error-on-line-0-wamp/

although your one will be different depending what version you use. The best method is to make a back up of your sql database and unistall WAMP (your WWW folder should remain). Then reinstall!

see:
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can follow below steps:

1. start -> run -> services.msc
2. find "wampapache" -> Right click -> Start
3. find "wampmysqld" -> Right click -> Start

If you use wamp on regular basis, it might be a good idea to change "Startup Type" from "Manual" to "Automatic".

Hope this helps.

Note: You must be an admin to perform these operations.

Answer (score 0):

I think You have Downloanded a 32-bit wamp and your system may be in 64-bit.

download for a 64-bit wampsever. It works

Answer (score 0):

Did you install wampserver 2.5?

In WAMPServer 2.5 release notes and corrections it is mentionned:
Do not install this version over an existing version ,

follow the steps : 
Installing a new release of WAMPServer

Answer (score 0):

Come to find out, this error is encountered when your `wampmanager.ini` file is empty. I suspect this may be the effect of an unclean exit of Wamp Server.

Luckily, I had a secondary install of WAMP Server sitting on another machine, so I was able to paste in the following file contents and was back up and running in no time:

Your configuration file can generally be found in: c:/wamp/wampmanager.ini. Please note this configuration file was pulled from WAMP Server 2.5

Reference : http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2014/12/repairing-your-wamp-configuration-file

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in `wampmanager.ini` file. It could have been corrupted. Try and replace the file or copy the [code here](http://pastebin.com/wCMBr60Z) into your file.