# Starting Wamp on Windows 10

Tags: php, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I was using Wamp server on my Windows 7 pc behind me. It was working fine. I then installed Windows 10, Wamp started but was orange and could not start apache. I then reinstalled the latest Wamp in the hope to fix it however now it gives me an error when I try to launch it:

The configuration file contains an error on line 325: [EParseError] Parameter "Service" specifies an unknown server.

I can use Xampp but I have gotten used to Wamp so if someone knows how to fix this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try solutions from the answers from this [post][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645833/wamp-server-startup-error-can-not-startup-ephase-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that Windows 10 uses port 80 by default. Forgetting that wamp is really badly written and can't install over itself you need to simply change the port it is running on. Hope it helps anyone else having this problem.

Comment: Well actually all you really needed to do was uninstall IIS especially if you are not using it. As well as any of these `Web Deploy 2.0 (Web Deployment Agent Service)`, `MS Sql Server Reporting service.`, 
`BranchCache`, `SQL Server VSS Writer` that also share using port 80 with IIS.

Comment: And whats that phrase..... Oh yes i remember _'A bad workman always blames his tools'_

Comment: Simply changing the port is a lot better than uninstalling components. If the tool does not function and needs fixing then it is a bad tool. I installed Xampp anyway and it is been a dream ever since. Unlike Wamp it by default listens on 2 ports.